# Conditionnally render html parent without affecting children elements

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3

Let's say I have a component with this html code:

```
<template lang="html">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child">
            some content
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I want to render only the child element when a condition is met, to obtain this result:

```
<template lang="html">
    <div id="child">
        some content
    </div>
</template>
```

I first thought I could use `v-if`, but if I use v-if to conditionally render the parent element, its children will not be rendered when the condition is not met.

Comment: You need to write `<div id="child">` twice with v-if. If this results in a lot of dupe code, this means that you need to extract it to a component.

Comment: I thought about it, but I hope there's a better solution

Comment: You didn't specify Vue version. It matters

Comment: Yeah, I Use Vue 3

Comment: In 2, this could be achieved with Fragment and dynamic component. AFAIK `template` fragments work differently in 3. Probably something like https://github.com/ambit-tsai/fragment-for-vue . Any way, extracting `<div id="child">...` to a component so you wouldn't have more than 1 dupe line is universal correct solution.